# Xcode8.1 fails to codesign .bundle file

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, xcode8

After upgrading from Xcode8.0 to Xcode8.1, code signing fails for couple of bundle of Braintree.

After trying a lot, not able to find any solution.
Here I posting error logs.

```
CodeSign /Users/Arvaan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InstaCare-bielwuzaqgqgngcpffjnjballruv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Braintree-Drop-In-Localization.bundle
cd /Users/Arvaan/Documents/BitBucket/iOS/2016/Xcode8_1/New/Instacare/Pods
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode8_1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode8_1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode8_1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" 

Signing Identity:     "-"

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none /Users/Arvaan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InstaCare-bielwuzaqgqgngcpffjnjballruv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Braintree-Drop-In-Localization.bundle

/Users/Arvaan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InstaCare-bielwuzaqgqgngcpffjnjballruv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Braintree-Drop-In-Localization.bundle: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Project running fine on device and also able to create archive to distribute it. But not working on simulator.

If any one facing same issue then please help me.

Comment: It looks like a localization error. Probable the simulator uses another preferred language. You can set this up in the settings app (General -> Languages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got answer from this [Apple Developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66538) link.Here also so many solution suggested but what working for me is below.

> Select Pods in the navigation --> TARGETS --> your BundleName --> Signing(Enable Development Signing) --> Identity(Choose Info.plist File).

1. First select Pod(.xcworkspace) in your project.
2. Then selecr bundle which causing code sign errors.
   Here in my case `Braintree-Drop-In-Localization.bundle` and `Pods-InstaCare-Braintree-Braintree-Drop-In-Localization.bundle` are two files causing error.

[image]

3. Then click on `Choose Info.plist file` button. It will display pop up as like below.

[image]

4. Clean Project and Run. It will work on simulator as well on device.